# Using Cufon on ASP.NET MVC site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cufon

I have such menu on my ASP.NET MVC site

```
<ul class="site-nav sf-menu">
<li @CurrentItem("Index")>@Html.ActionLink(Resources.Global.Home_Menu_Home, "Index", "Home")</li>
<li @CurrentItem("WhoWeAre")>@Html.ActionLink(Resources.Global.Home_Menu_WhoWeAre, "WhoWeAre", "Home")</li>
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
</ul>
```

(Names for menu items are taken from Global.resx, I can't change that).
And I try to use Cufon for my menu

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/cufon-yui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/Aller_400.font.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function () {
        Cufon.replace('ul.site-nav li a', { fontFamily: 'Aller', hover: true });
    });
</script>
```

but my menu items disappear (because they are formed dynamical)
So, I try to use such script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
var replace = function () {
    var gotinside = false
    $('ul.site-nav').each(function (i) {
        gotinside = true;
        if (i < 1) {
            Cufon.replace('ul.site-nav li a', { fontFamily: 'Aller', hover: true });
        }
    })
    if (!gotinside)
        setTimeout(replace, 1000);
}
replace();
});
</script>
```

but it doesn't work too.
Help me please with this problem.